# When saying "making a donation on behalf of somebody" who has the money acually?

Tags: money

I was wondering when saying "make a donation on behalf of someone" does on behalf mean in the name of ? or it means someone who owns the money?

Thank you .

Comment: ***On behalf of*** : *done for another person’s benefit or support, or because you are representing the interests of that person* - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on-behalf-of-someone

Comment: from the expression "the donation is made by A on behalf of B"  can one tell that the money belongs to B?

Comment: No, B never sees the money.  It goes from A to the recipient.  B is only mentioned.

Comment: Thank you!! Can I ask advice on appropriate expression?

Comment: @Felicia.C: Saying X made a donation to Y on behalf of Z would be correct usage. In this case, X owned the money and donated it to Y in the name of Z.

Comment: Thank you !! Can I ask if I wish to express that it is A who owns the money and B helps to "make" the donation? say that B sends the money online? does that make sense?